# Combining lists which have the same column names, but NOT joining them

Tags: r

I have 3 lists 1 want to combine. These lists contain different data points, but the same types of data. I want to place these into 1 list for export side-by-side. For example,

```
A$a <- c(1,2,3)
A$b <- c(2,3,4)
B$a <- c(1,3,5)
B$b <- c(2,4,6)
```

I want to have a new list, C, which has columns A$a, A$b, B$a, and B$b as separate columns (and in that order). How can I do this?

Comment: Try `lapply(names(A), function(x) cbind(A[x], B[x]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
C<-c(A,B)
names(C) <- paste0(c("A","B"),names(C))

C
$Aa
[1] 1 2 3

$Bb
[1] 2 3 4

$Aa
[1] 1 3 5

$Bb
[1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: Or just `c(A = A, B = B)`